# What is causing the server name to be malformed when publishing a printer to AD?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-printer

I have a printer that exists as `\\printserver01\printer`

For whatever reason, when I publish/add it to AD, part of the name gets cut off.  For example, it becomes `\\printserver0\printer`

When users go to search for the printer through the Devices and Printers option on their desktop, it lists just fine as "printer on printserver01", but if you do a search in AD for the printer, you'll see the server name is listed as "printserver0" instead of "printserver01".  I tried using FQDN, but the issue still remains with the last character being chopped off.

Has anyone come across this before?  How can this be resolved?

Comment: Is that _actually_ the server's name, or is it something else? What I'm getting at, is the full name of the print server > 15 characters?

Comment: No, that's an example.  The actual server name is less than 15 chars.  It doesn't seem to matter how long the name is, AD seems to chop off the last char when it adds it, but displays the correct info if you list it from the user end, but fails to add on the user end, due to the missing char on the server name.

Comment: Ok. If it was > 15 characters, my guess would be a NetBIOS issue (I had that just the other week), but that was my only guess. Sorry.